# Debug node process with different PID on every request

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code, remix.run

guys!

I'm trying to debug a remix grunge-stack (https://github.com/remix-run/grunge-stack) with a simple launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "command": "npm run dev",
      "name": "Run npm run dev",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "node-terminal",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true,
    },
  ]
}
```

but when the application starts, every request has a different PID (arc, https://arc.codes/docs/en/get-started/quickstart, does this to emulate how AWS Lambdas works)

```
⚬ Sandbox Users/gnllucena/git/app/server (pid 63404) emitted 'close' (code 'null', signal 'SIGINT')
⚬ Sandbox Users/gnllucena/git/app/server (pid 63758) emitted 'close' (code 'null', signal 'SIGINT')
⚬ Sandbox Users/gnllucena/git/app/server (pid 63773) emitted 'close' (code 'null', signal 'SIGINT')
```

but the vscode don't know how to handle this debug session.

Does anybody knows how to debug an application like this?

Comment: Attach debugger by pid

Comment: Hello, @SeverinPappadeux, how exactly would I attach a PID that keeps changing on every request?

Comment: small script watching log and on new record with request get pid and launch debugger?

Comment: Unfortunately the logs are only outputted when the response is flushed from the server, there's no way I can use this approach =/